# Angular Material dialog center to specified parent element

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular Material's dialog pops up in the center of the browser view port horizontally and vertically, which is great. But sometimes I want the popup dialog to be positioned to the center of a specified parent component, rather than the browser view port. I didn't see an option like parent in the docs. I wonder if there's any easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
`const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContactsComponent, {
 position: { right: '25px'}
});`
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of it. But I wonder if I can specify a parent element to which the popup will be centered.